# Html.ActionLink generates the wrong link based on routes.MapRoute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I guess I still don't understand routing.

I have three controllers

- AdminController
- DashboardController
- ProjectGroupsController

For Dashboard, I want the url to be `/Dashboard/`. For Admin section, however, I want two different controllers. `/Admin/Overview` should be using `AdminController`, and `/Admin/ProjectGroups/` should be using `ProjectGroupsController`.

This is how my routing looks like

```
 routes.MapRoute(
          name: "AdminOverivew",
           url: "Admin/Overview",
           defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Overview" },
           namespaces: new[] { "Com.Controllers" }
        );

    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "AdminSubs",
       url: "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
       namespaces: new[] { "Com.Controllers" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new[] {"Com.Controllers"}
    );
```

*Note, the reason for the 2nd route is because I have many more controllers under admin section.

It's working.. except, the URL that HTML.ActionLink generates is wrong. `@Html.ActionLink("Dashboard", "Index", "Dashboard"........)` generates `/Admin/Dashboard` when it should be `/Dashboard`.

However, `@Html.ActionLink("Project Groups", "Index", "ProjecGroups".....)` generates the correct url `/Admin/ProjectGroups`

If I take out the 2nd routes.MapRoute (AdminSubs), then the situation is reversed. Dashboard gets the right url, `/Dashboard` then Project Groups becomes `/ProjectGroups` when it should remain `/Admin/ProjectGroups`

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a few more explicit routes, since the router doesn't know the difference between the "catch all" of `Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}` and `{controller}/{action}/{id}`. The first matched pattern is the one it uses.

You either need to get rid of the `Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}` and anything under the admin prefix needs to be explicitly assigned as a route, or the opposite, remove the `{controller}/{action}/{id}` route, and explicitly create routes that should be apart of the root directory.

Comment: Thanks @steve. So you are saying, for "ProjectGroups", I should assign /Admin/ProjectGroups/...controller="ProjecGroups" correct? Just like what I did with "/Admin/Overview"? 

What about HTMl.ActionLink()? It's still generating the wrong url though. [Edit - Never mind. It's correct now that I assign explicit routes/controllers].

Comment: @Liming exactly right. You should add extra admin route that way. If it's still generating the wrong URL, make sure it's above the catch all `{controller}/{action}/{id}` one. Also for what it's worth, you may want to take a look into [Areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx) which you'd be able to seperate the admin and main controllers using the catch alls with and without `/Admin`.

Comment: Thanks again @Steve. Given there are many routes within Admin section,the routing could become really bloated very quickly. Just looked into Area, seems like it's exactly designed for this type of scenario! Greatly appreciate it.